# How to show $f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}, & \text{when } x \neq 0,\\ 0, & \text{when } x = 0. \end{cases}$ is of bounded variation?

Tags: analysis, bounded-variation

> Prove or disprove:  $f(x) = \begin{cases}     \frac{\sin(x)}{x}, & \text{when } x \neq 0,\\  0,  & \text{when } x = 0. \end{cases}$ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$ and $\sup_{p \in P} V(f,p) =2$.

**My try:**

Let $p=\{0,x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n-1},1\}$

$$
\begin{split}
V(f,p) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n}|f(x_{k})-f(x_{k-1})| \\
       &= \left|\frac{\sin(x_{1})}{x_{1}}\right|
        + \left|\frac{\sin(x_{2})}{x_{2}}-\frac{\sin(x_{1})}{x_{1}}\right|
        + \ldots \\
       &+ \left|\frac{\sin(x_{n-1})}{x_{n-1}}-\frac{\sin(x_{n-2})}{x_{n-2}}\right|
        + \left|\sin(1)-\frac{\sin(x_{n-1})}{x_{n-1}}\right|
\end{split}
$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried the definition of variation  but I was not capable of reaching the result

Comment: could you update your questions with what you tried and how it did not work? would be much easier to guide you that way

Comment: I tried to make the variation bounded by $2 $ but I am not capable of doing it

Comment: You can use that if $f$ is $C^1$, then $V_a^b(f)=\int_a^b\lvert f'(x)\rvert~\mathrm{d}x$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588713/relation-of-total-variation-of-a-function-f-and-the-integral-of-f) for the details

Comment: @Lorago But the derivative of my function is non elementary function  so can't be integrated easily.

Comment: My comment to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4379592/13130) might be helpful.

Comment: It bothers me that the function is being defined to have a *discontinuity* at $x=0$, since $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin x/x = 1$.  Would you mind checking that the problem statement did not become garbled in its presentation here?  That said, I'm voting to leave open.